# how do you install MAT via source in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am unable to install MAT via Eclipse gui. Maybe it has something to do with firewall. I tried this:

```
Install MAT plugins
1.Eclipse —> Help Menu —> Install New Software —> Add
2.Enter below information


Name : MAT

Location: http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.5/update-site/
```

I've downloaded the source code from

```
Source:http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php
```

How do I install this to Eclipse. I tried unzipping it, putting it a directory but Eclipse not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mean you downloaded MemoryAnalyzer-1.5.0.201505271423.zip to install this using 'Help > Install New Software... > Add...'.

Click the 'Archive' button on 'Add Repository' dialog and select the zip file. Enter a name and click OK.

You should now be shown the contents of the zip in the main install window.